# drop-down menu disrupts other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a navigation bar with a drop-down menu (will add another one later). When the drop-menu is pressed, it shifts all nav links to the right. Desired behavior is all nav links are static. I tried using `fixed` on the `div` with an `absolute` css on the `li` tags but I.E. would render the `li` tags outside of the parent div.

My current implementation is using `float:left` but this isn't producing expected results either. The drop-down menu is the one labeled "Solace". Any help or suggestions are appreciated. I have created a demo which illustrates my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/xbB4M/1/.

Also, a side-question. If this warrants a new post, just let me know, and I will open a new question. Whenever a user clicks the drop-down menu, how can I listen for the next mouse click to close the drop-down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your `.menu` class an `absolute` position it should stop the other menu items from sliding over to the right. As for your second question if you check the working example I added another click event handler for the menu items and if they are clicked it will close the menu.

Give this a try:

```
.menu {
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:#17406B;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/xbB4M/5/